# How to handle custom token authentication with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

My application needs to access various apis, which use tokens to authenticated, but do not conform to oauth2 specification. Because of this I cannot use `IdentityModel.Client` library. How can I work with such libraries?

Example flow to query endpoint1:

1. App queries /auth to get token
2. App caches token locally
3. App queries resource with token in cookie (don't ask)
4. Token expires
5. App blocks all other requests and queries another token (single time)
6. All waiting queries are resumed with new token

Comment: The simple answer is "use HttpClient library", it gives an access to internals of any HTTP request/response. You also may have a look to https://flurl.dev/

Comment: Can you provide some examples how to do so? I guess there is some library doing this, but I do not know which or how.

Comment: Also Flurl looks like it doesn't help at all, and it uses extension methods on strings in disgusting way.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what examples you want from me. There is a small tutorial how to use HttpClient: https://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/

Comment: Example flow which I want to achieve is in query. I just don't want to reinvent wheel and do everything manually. Also your tutorial does not really help, as this code needs to sit inside `HttpRequestHandler` so it is transient to client of the api.